# width_bucket not returning empty buckets

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgres 9.5.3, `width_bucket()` is returning fewer than the specified number of buckets if there are no values to fill some of the buckets. Is there a way to make these empty buckets show up?

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE metrics (val INT);
INSERT INTO metrics (val) VALUES(1), (2), (3), (8), (10);
SELECT width_bucket(val, 1, 10, 9) FROM metrics;
```

returns:

```
width_bucket
------------
           1
           2
           3
           8
          10
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`width_bucket()` doesn't exactly *return* all the buckets.  It returns the bucket that each value is assigned to.  If no values are assigned to a bucket, then that bucket value is not returned.

It is not missing buckets.  There is simply no data in the buckets.

If you want to count the sizes of buckets -- and to include all of them -- then generate the buckets using `generate_series()`:

```
SELECT g.n, COUNT(m.val) 
FROM generate_series(1, 10) g(n) LEFT JOIN
     metrics m 
     ON width_bucket(val, 1, 10, 9) = g.n
GROUP BY g.n
ORDER BY g.n;
```

Comment: thanks @gordon I had to change it a bit to work with numbers not in the range 1-10, but the idea was the same :)